# How would you code for this greedy algorithm qns where we must select the routes of the players but the routes cannot be repeated?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, greedy

[image]

[image]

v = 1 is where the game will end with the player at the point
v = 2 is where the game will end when the player goes back to the original point at (0,0)

My current approach is to find the differences of all possible routes, after which i would insert flagID as the key and value as the value into the dictionary. I am stuck from here onwards... can anyone advise?

Comment: what have you tried in terms of *psuedocode or code* itself?, also what is **Q1**?

Comment: hi you can ignore qns 1, i have tried coding but am stuck in extracting all the differences between all of the flags

Comment: can someone answer this? I am honestly sick of waiting